# Tonic getElementById()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, tonic

I'm trying to setup a code example on tonicdev.com for my open source react component hosted on Npm.

Here's the code I'm trying to run (live edit on tonicdev.com [here](https://tonicdev.com/56dd5ce7afca530d006e8ff9/56dd5ce7afca530d006e8ffa)):

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Calendar, CalendarControls} = require('react-yearly-calendar');

function onDatePicked(date) {
  alert(date);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Calendar
    year={2016}
    onPickDate={onDatePicked}
  />,
  document.getElementById('calendar')
);
```

Tonic complains because it doesn't have a `document` selector:

> No document object in node.
>   Tonic is a node environment, so document and other browser features won't exist.

But it does not provide an alternative. Since this is a React component I should render it with ReactDOM.render, which requires as second argument a `domContainerNode`. How can I obtain one in Tonic?

More generally: am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to run React examples in Tonic?

Comment: You can use renderToString to do this in Tonic btw. https://tonicdev.com/tolmasky/56ec2fcc5029631100e6518c

Comment: @FranciscoRyanTolmaskyI That's cool! I guess that's read only, isn't it? I mean, I can't have any onClick handler in React, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gavino, you got it all wrong. Tonic is a node prototyping service which means it allows you run / test code for nodeJS.

As you may already know, nodeJS is a backend service which means it is server-side. Therefore, a `document` or any other browser-specific ( client-side features ) are not available.

Use `nodeJS` to get data out of your server towards the `/public` folder as that is the place in which you want to use the following:

```
function onDatePicked(date) {
  alert(date);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Calendar
    year={2016}
    onPickDate={onDatePicked}
  />,
  document.getElementById('calendar')
);
```

Comment: You're right! I thought Tonic was like jsbin or similar in an npm-ish environment, so I planned to use it to allow people to preview the component without downloading it.. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @GavinoGrifoni if the answer is correct, you can accept my answer so the question gets marked as solved.